# Decline commits due to incorrect information

Tags: gitlab, hook

How can I automatic decline pushes in Gitlab due to incorrect formatting (I have rules (.clang-format file) for it).

Comment: "Simply" by writing a server hook.

Comment: Can you explain how to?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure `Push rules`. It's possible configure it by project or more globally at group level.

For projects, go to `Settings` > `repository` and edit either `Require expression in commit messages` or `Reject expression in commit messages` with regular expression :

[image]

For groups, settings are the same but the configuration is behind `Push rules` button in the left menu :

[image]